# How to add site navigation (ascx) to MVC _Layout.cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am migrating a WebForm asp.net project to MVC. I copied and pasted the masterpage content to the _Layout.cshtml page. Now I got the side panel for the site Navigation. In the Webform, as shown in the code below, the  put the site navigation to the far left.  I tried both the enf and ~/Views/SiteNavigation.ascx, but the site navigation control is  not appearing  when I load up the page. Just a blank left panel. Any help is appreciated.

```
            <div class="horizontalTabBarContent" id="mainTabContent">

                <enf:SiteNavigation  ID="ISRNavigation" />
                @*<a href="~/Views/SiteNavigation.ascx">~/Views/SiteNavigation.ascx</a>*@


                <div id="main">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ISRContent" >
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>

            </div>

        </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

I gess you're looking for `Html.RenderPartial` helper.

In Razor syntax it will be:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/SiteNavigation.ascx"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

A view in MVC is basic HTML code in which you can add razor syntax. The "Razor code" will be parsed server side and will generate html output to bind models, generate valid url etc.

Here is an example of what your _Layout.cshtml view might look like:

```
<div class="horizontalTabBarContent" id="mainTabContent">
    <div ID="ISRNavigation" />
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/YourPartialNavigationView") //Your navigation bar will be rendered here

            <div id="main">
                @RenderBody() //Body html code will be rendered here
            </div>

        </div>
```

**MVC Projet don't support the asp:htmltags syntax**

Answer (score 0):

in MVC instead of web forms user control, you should use partial views and by using of Helper functions like RenderPartial and Partial you could render it througth your view !!
and also instead of using PlaceHolder you should use Section !
you can Google for both topics : partialView , Section